# On The Way, In The Way

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

For these two sentences:

> They discussed the law ***in the way*** in which it affects people.
>   They discussed the law ***on the way*** in which it affects people.

Could "*in the way*" and "*on the way*" be the same?

Comment: At very first read, I thought law is an impediment, a hurdle ;) *in the way* is generally used for that. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+way

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so.

The first example is OK, though you could leave out "in which" to simplify it a bit. Or possibly:

> They discussed the law **as** it affects people.

Or in other words:

> They discussed **how** the law affects people.

The relationship here is between the law and the people.

The second example doesn't make sense to me. An example using the bolded phrase might be:

> They discussed the law **on the way** elevators need to be operated.

Here, elevator operation is a description of the law.

Comment: So, in the first sentence, "*in the way*" goes with "*discussed*"?

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer, trying to describe the relationship of the clauses better.

Comment: So, this "*They discussed the law* **as** *it affects people*"

is it closer in structure to 
"*They discussed the way the law affects people*"
than to  

"*They discussed the law*"
?

Comment: @meatie Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you heard the sentence and weren't sure which preposition was said, I'd say that the speakers probably said neither "in" nor "on", but "and":

> They discussed the law and the way in which it affects people.

Neither of your given sentences are really correct; "in the way" and "on the way" don't make sense in the stated context.

Comment: What would "They discussed the law ***as*** it affects people" translate to?